# Error Converting Jupyter Notebook to PDF after installing MikTex, pandoc and nbconvert

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have been trying to convert my Jupyter Notebook into PDF(via LaTeX).
I have installed all packages in the MikTeX console, pandoc and nbconvert.
Yet, I still see the following error.

Your advice is very much appreciated!

[MikTeX packages all installed and updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4jLG.png)

[Pandoc installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9foGp.png)

Error when i ran the code on anaconda prompt and when clicking File->Download as-> PDF via LaTeX (.pdf):

```
(base) C:\Users\justm>jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to pdf
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook notebook.ipynb to pdf
[NbConvertApp] Support files will be in notebook_files\
[NbConvertApp] Making directory .\notebook_files
[NbConvertApp] Making directory .\notebook_files
[NbConvertApp] Making directory .\notebook_files
[NbConvertApp] Making directory .\notebook_files
[NbConvertApp] Making directory .\notebook_files
[NbConvertApp] Making directory .\notebook_files
[NbConvertApp] Writing 66012 bytes to .\notebook.tex
[NbConvertApp] Building PDF
[NbConvertApp] Running xelatex 3 times: ['xelatex', '.\\notebook.tex', '-quiet']
[NbConvertApp] CRITICAL | x failed: xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet
notebook.tex:385: Unable to load picture or PDF file '
notebook.tex:404: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:404: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:404: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:404: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:490: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:490: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:490: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:490: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:600: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:600: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:600: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:600: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:896: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:896: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:896: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:896: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:1007: Unable to load picture or PDF file '
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\justm\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-nbconvert.EXE\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 268, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 340, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 510, in convert_notebooks
    self.convert_single_notebook(notebook_filename)
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 481, in convert_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.export_single_notebook(notebook_filename, resources, input_buffer=input_buffer)
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\nbconvertapp.py", line 410, in export_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=resources)
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\exporter.py", line 179, in from_filename
    return self.from_file(f, resources=resources, **kw)
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\exporter.py", line 197, in from_file
    return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(file_stream, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\pdf.py", line 185, in from_notebook_node
    self.run_latex(tex_file)
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\pdf.py", line 156, in run_latex
    self.latex_count, log_error, raise_on_failure)
  File "c:\users\justm\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbconvert\exporters\pdf.py", line 145, in run_command
    command=command, output=out))
nbconvert.exporters.pdf.LatexFailed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex .\notebook.tex -quiet" command:
notebook.tex:385: Unable to load picture or PDF file '
notebook.tex:404: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:404: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:404: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:404: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:490: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:490: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:490: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:490: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:600: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:600: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:600: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:600: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:896: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:896: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:896: Missing number, treated as zero
notebook.tex:896: Illegal unit of measure (
notebook.tex:1007: Unable to load picture or PDF file '
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite old question, but I just stumbled upon it as well. The problem is that something in the LaTeX code requires the `calc` package which, however, is not imported.

In my case the notebook contained tables which contained calculations for the column with, such as this one

```
\begin{longtable}[]{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{(\columnwidth - 10\tabcolsep) * \real{0.17}}lllll@{}}
```

This was introduced by pandoc 2.11.2 with [this commit](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/bd7c9eb32be7c5499f4a50cb4b5f138f9eb919e8#diff-64a9e5fa4509dce2699276c9e39993b4474e2446c3e86941a2f78a379f8c4079). However, as I used a custom template file it missed `\usepackage{calc}`. After adding it it worked perfectly. It is also not contained in the current nbconvert package (see [#1566](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1566)).

Also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598068/error-converting-pandoc-tables-from-md-to-pdf) and [this thread in pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/1AKiYXTrqXg).