# Error converting pandoc tables from .md to PDF

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc, xelatex, miktex

I try to convert Markdown files to PDF with

`FOR %%i IN (*.md) DO pandoc "%%~fi" -o "%%~dpni.pdf" --template=weber-export.tex --pdf-engine=xelatex`

But it wont convert pandoc-tables. instead there occurs an error saying

```
Error producing PDF.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   (
l.357 ...columnwidth - 2\tabcolsep) * \real{0.33}}
```

Simply Version of the tables it wont convert are :

```
 Consumption / yield
---------------------

+--+---+--+
|  |   |  |
|  |   |  |
|  |   |  |
+--+---+--+
|  |   |  |
|  |   |  |
|  |   |  |
+--+---+--+
|  |   |  |
|  |   |  |
|  |   |  |
+--+---+--+
```

and

```
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
  Type                            Sales unit   Number
  ------------------------------- ------------ ----------------------
  Plastic bucket                  30 liters    18 buckets
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

like its explained in the [Pandoc User's Guid](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extensions)

I have installed Miktex 2.9 and pandoc 2.11.2 on Win 10

Without the tables, the conversion is doing well, even when i try out tables without the first line like

```
  Type                            Sales unit   Number
  ------------------------------- ------------ ----------------------
  Plastic bucket                  30 liters    18 buckets
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

it works.

any suggestions? Is it a bug, or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your custom template does not load all necessary packages.

Add

```latex
\usepackage{calc,array}
```

to your template to ensure the necessary commands are available.