# nbconvert fails to convert to html or pdf

Tags: html, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I have been having the error

> nbconvert failed: 'application/vnd.jupyter.widget-state+json'

when running `jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb` in terminal, tried export from vscode ipynb, or jupyter notebook
and have not been able to find any reasonable help googling. I have texlive, pandoc and all necessary packages installed as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916093/convert-ipynb-to-pdf-in-jupyter?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62207577/error-converting-jupyter-notebook-to-pdf-after-installing-miktex-pandoc-and-nbc?rq=1). Any help on the cause of this?

Comment: Hi Toonia and welcome to SO ! Can you elaborate on how is run the command (from the terminal, jupyter notebook, jupyterlab, ...) and add the used command (e.g `jupyter nbconvert --to html notebook.ipynb` ) ?

Comment: I got the error in all cases: from terminal, vscode, and jupyter notebook

Comment: Ok, maybe update your question with this comment so it is easier for other to get all the information. Have you tried converting a dummy notebook (with e.g only a title and a block of code) ? If this fails we will need to know how `nbconvert` was installed (with `conda`, `pip`, ...) to have a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).